# JCO_ERROR_RESOURCE: Destination does not exist

Tags: java, eclipse, sapjco3

I am using below Java code for SAP connectivity and I don't know what to put into `getDestination()` method. Please guide me how to find value of destination or what to put into it?

```java
 createDestinationDataFile("ABAP_AS_WITHOUT_POOLs", connectProperties);
 try {
             JCoDestination destination = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("**********");        //Doubt
             System.out.println("Attributes:");
             System.out.println(destination.getAttributes());
             destination.ping();
         } catch (JCoException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the name of your destination into    `JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("YourDestName")`. If using the default JCo infrastructure implementations, then you need to create a property text file named `YourDestName.jcoDestination` in the current working directory. This file must contain all your logon parameters like `jco.client.ashost=hostname.in.your.domain`. Valid and required properties are described in the JavaDoc of interface `com.sap.conn.jco.ext.DestinationDataProvider`.